# How to install LEO-NANO150N Leoxys mini USB Wifi adapter on ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have a Leoxys mini USB adapter ([LEP - NANO 150 N](http://www.leoxsys.com/products/wifiadapter.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_color_plus.tpl&product_id=39&category_id=10))

When I download the drivers, there is a folder named LINUX. But I find more folders inside it namely MT7601u , RT537x_RT3x7x and RT5572_RT3572.

I do not know what are those and how to install them. How do I install those drivers?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lsusb

Comment: Extract the DPA_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.3_20130313.tar.bz2 file in the MT7601U folder using the command: `tar xvjf filename.tar.bz2` Change directory to the extracted folder and post the output of the `make` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the linux drivers from the product website and all didnt work for me for this device.

To get it to work, just follow these steps (make sure you have an active internet connection):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands in sequence:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
mkdir ~/RTL8188EU
cd ~/RTL8188EU
git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -v ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu/rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Wireless should spring to life.

[source](http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=11261.0)

Answer (score 1):

Here is drivers for your device: [MT7601 STA driver](https://code.launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/mt7601). Prepared packages based on source code [porjo/mt7601](https://github.com/porjo/mt7601). Before installation, please check that your device is supported:

```
$ lsusb
```

> According to the driver these USB devices are supported:
>
> 2955:1003
>   2955:1001
>   2955:0001
>   2A5F:1000
>   148F:760B
>   148F:7601
>   148F:6370
>   148F:7650

Here steps, how to use PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601 
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mt7601
```